# Show the soft keyboard in Android with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, android-softkeyboard

I'm developing a Web App and trying to find a way to show the soft keyboard in Android browser when user tap a `canvas`. I found a very simple way to do that with iOS, but with Android seems not possible.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="width:100px;height:50px;background-color:gray" tabindex="0" contenteditable="true"></div>
...
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCanvas').click(function(e){ $(this).focus(); });
})
```

Above code works in iOS, but not in Android. Also I don't really like the `contenteditable=true`, because it shows a blinking cursor in iOS and tested with `div` in Android it lets you write directly into the `div`.

I googled to find a solution, but none of the solutions works.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try with this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCanvas').click(function(e){
        $(this).focus();
    });
    $('#button').click(function(e) {
        $('#myCanvas').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Add this line in your Menifest file in Activity tag.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

Comment: I tried adding a button as you suggested, but no way. The `canvas` takes the focus, because I see a yellow border around it, but the soft keyboard doesn't jump out.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear in the main description, but I'm not developing an Android App, but a Web App, so I have no way to set a Manifest.

Comment: you mean web app using phonegap ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, just a "simple" HTML page with a bunch of JS libs, so no PhoneGap, Appcelerator, Xamarin of something similar.